# How would I go about saying a character is on the run from the cops in the 1760s?

Tags: phrase-requests, eighteenth-century-english

I'm writing a short story set in 1767 and I don't feel like 'on the run from the cops' makes sense in that period. I know cops existed back then, the words just don't sit right with me in that scenario.

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'cops'. if you mean policemen in the modern sense then, no, they didn't exist in 1767.

Comment: *Where* is the story set?

Comment: It will depend a great deal on the location, since most places had no organized police force at the time.

Comment: Downvoted until you supply a place.  Happy to remove it and then upvote once you do.

Comment: @KillingTime & alphabet: To complete your comments, in the 18th century law enforcement and policing was left entirely to local initiative. There was no nationally organised police force. From the 1730s local improvement Acts often included provision for paid [watchmen or constables](https://www.parliament.uk/about/living-heritage/transformingsociety/laworder/policeprisons/overview/watchmenconstables/) to patrol towns at night, while rural areas had less formal arrangements.

Comment: The term "the cops" derived from "copper(s)" is dated from 1850s. There were *probably* bounties for  capturing thieves and murderers but you would need to do some research to be certain.

Answer (score 5):

The expression **fugitive from justice** can be found in publications from that period with Google Books. For example:

> It is not easy to conceive the anguish, with which I reflected upon my
> condition; and, perhaps, it would scarcely have been thought possible,
> that a person who was not a **fugitive from justice**, nor an enemy to
> labour, could be thus destitute even of the little that is essential
> to life, and in danger of perishing for want in the midst of a
> populous city ...
> [John Hawkesworth; *The Adventurer,* Vol.4](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Adventurer/3RdcAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fugitive%20from%20justice%22&pg=PA260&printsec=frontcover) (1756)

**Fugitive from justice** (n.)

> A person (such as a criminal suspect or witness) who tries to elude
> law enforcement especially by fleeing the jurisdiction : fugitive
>
> **The first known use of *fugitive from justice* was in 1735.**
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fugitive%20from%20justice)

**Fleeing from authorities** might also work. **On the run** (from authorities) is fine: the OED dates it to **1770**. *On the lam*, however, doesn't appear in print until 1897 according to the OED.

Comment: +1. "escape [the hand of] justice" can also be found in 17th century writing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the word **law** instead of the *means* of enforcement. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/law) has

> **law**
> a binding custom or practice of a community : a rule of conduct or action prescribed or formally recognized as binding or enforced by a controlling authority

So the sentence could be

> [The character] is on the run from **the law**.

Where **the law** means all the aspects of legitimacy and its enforcement.

Comment: Can you find examples of this from around the 1760s?